# How can I replace IDs in rows with another text in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a datasheet (I can use it as CSV file, Excel worksheet or MySQL database) with RID, CID, and NAME fields. RID and CID fields contains a number which refer another row in another table. For an example, here is one row:

```
5, Victoria, 12.
```

In another table, I have "5, LONDON" and in yet another table, it has "12, 221B" text.
What I need to do is, replace 5 with "London" text and 12 with "221B" text so that row will be,

```
LONDON, Victoria, 221B.
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe, you are looking for the `JOIN` statementm.
I am not sure what language you are using, but take a look at this links:

http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqljoins.php

http://mysqljoin.com/joins/inner-join-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks for the info. Actually this is not a MySQL database. This is just 3 separate CSV files and I'm looking for a user-friendly find-and-replace method with array support.

Comment: I read your links and understand that if I have a complete mysql database, it will be very easy to do it.

Comment: @Ayesh: Yes, it is very easy with MySql.  In fact, if you have a MySql instance up and running, it's also easy to load data from a .CSV file, using bulk load commands or a tool like PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: Thank you very much mellamokb and Oleg G.
But, later, I realized that CSVed, CSV Split(texby.com/wiki/split-csv-files-easily-free-csv-splitter), and "Advanced Bulk Replacer" could do the job.
I uploaded one table to ABR and ABR created a table of strings to replace. Then, I showed the other table and ABR replaced all the IDs with real names!
CSV Split helped me to do this without gettings my PC frozen and CSVed helped me to split columns in CSV file.
Actually when comparing with MySQL JOINs, I will go in circles if I use these softwares but we exactly know what we do if we use these softwares.

Answer (score 0):

What language are you planning to use?

If you are using SQL, you are pretty much limited to the data that is loaded into database tables or "poses" as database columns.

If you are using a common purpose 3GL like C, C++ or Java, you also get an option to implement an analog of join by yourself. If the lookup tables/data sets are small, you can arrange them in maps and do translation this way.